# Show that $E[|X|^r]^{1/r}$ is increasing

Tags: probability

I have the following problem:

Since $|X|^r$ is a convex function of X for $r \ge 1$, we have

$$E[|X|^r] \ge (E[|X|])^r $$
by Jensen's inequality. Deduce from this that $(E[|X|^r)^{1/r}$ is an increasing function of r for $r \ge 0$.

I don't know how to start. I don't understand why, if convexity is only for $r \ge 1$, would the function be increasing when $r$ is between 0 and 1 as well.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $0<r<s$ then

$$(E(\lvert X\rvert^{r}))^{\frac{s}{r}}\le E(\lvert X\rvert^{r\cdot\frac{s}{r}})=E(\lvert X\rvert^{s})$$

Comment: I'm not sure how I can use this. What is the outline of what you're thinking of?